# Maximise $z = \frac{y}{2x+2y}+\frac{50-y}{200-2x-2y}$ given that $x+y$ is non zero and $x+y<100$. Also, $x\leq50$ and $y\leq50$ and non-negative.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

Z is actually a probability function. I am finding where the probability is maximized. But I could find no way how to maximize this function.

Original question is as follows:

Mr A wants to join a Gamer's club. There are two identical boxes filled with Red and Green balls, and he has to pick up a green ball in order to join the club. You are required to allocate balls in such a way that the probability of A joining The Gamer's club is maximized and boxes should be non-empty. There are 50 red and 50 green balls in total. What is the maximum probability?

** I have taken the number of Green balls in Box 1 as x and red balls in Box 1 as y. And hence I have created the probability function given in the question title.**

The maximum probability occurs where there is only 1 green ball and 0 red ball in Box 1 and the value of probability is 0.747. I cannot figure a way out of how to reach this number.

All I want is a rule book method in how to proceed in such type of questions.

Comment: Are $x,y$ non negative? Guess so, given the original question.

Comment: Yes, I have also added the original question in description.

Comment: what happens if you put all the balls in one bin and he picks the other?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question - either box should contain at least one ball that is it should be non-empty

Comment: Intuitively, start with green balls all in one box and red balls in the other. The odds he wins is 0.5.  Then move a green ball to the red box. The odds keep going up until there is only one green ball left

Answer (score 0):

Introducing new variable $p=2(x+y)$ leads to:

$$f(y,p)=\frac{y}{p}+\frac{50-y}{200-p}$$

New variables for convenience:

$$y=50r \\ p=50 s$$

$$g(r,s)=\frac{r}{s}+\frac{1-r}{4-s}$$

$$0 \leq r \leq 1, \qquad 0 < s < 4$$

Now we use the usual derivative method:

$$g_r=\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{4-s}=0$$

$$g_s=-\frac{r}{s^2}+\frac{1-r}{(4-s)^2}=0$$

From these equations we have:

$$s_0=2 \\ r_0 = \frac{1}{2}$$

However, the tests show this is not a maximum. Neither it's a minimum, more likely a saddle point, though I haven't checked properly.

---

Since we haven't been able to find a maximum point in this region, that means that the maximum is achieved somewhere on the boundary.

And unfortunately, this simply means that we have $s \to 0$ or $s \to 4$ where the function becomes unbounded.